# Roblox Studio Printing Wrong Value

Tags: lua, roblox

I am writing a piece of code on Roblox Studio to change some properties depending on the value of `LightStaus.Value`. The code below is what I have so far however it isn't working properly.

```lua
while true do
    if script.Parent.Parent.LightStatus.Value == 1 then
        script.Parent.Material = "Neon"
        script.Parent.PointLight.Enabled = true
        script.Parent.SpotLight.Enabled = true
    else
        script.Parent.Material = "SmoothPlastic"
        script.Parent.PointLight.Enabled = false
        script.Parent.SpotLight.Enabled = false
    end
    print(script.Parent.Parent.LightStatus.Value)
    wait(1)
end
```

My code should print the value of `LightStatus.Value` however it is not doing this as the images below show. It prints 0 even though the value is 1. Any help is appreciated.

---

Printing 0's:

[image: Printing 0]

---

Value set to 0:

[image: Value set to 1]

Comment: BTW, the script is in a normal script. Should I try Local Script?

Comment: Do you have any other scripts that modify the LightStatus's Value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the glitch!
I was changing the value of `LightStatus.Value` locally, so it wasn't updating on the client side which is why it looked like it was set to `true`, but it was saying it was set to `false`. You can read more about client/server [here](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Roblox-Client-Server-Model)